# Casting Behavior of apply Function in R

Tags: r

I am struggling with a particular aspect of R that I can't quite seem to wrap my head around.

Consider the standard iris data-set, seen as follows:

```
head(iris, 5)

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

If I wanted to manipulate this dataframe row by row, I could do it in a number of ways, including the apply function.

What I am struggling to understand however, is why the column types change when passed into the apply function.

For example, the current structure iris is:

```
> str(iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

However, if I run the following code, I see that Species, which was a factor, is now a character:

```
checkDataType <- function(df) {
  return(typeof(df['Species']))
}

apply(iris[1:5,], 1, checkDataType)

          1           2           3           4           5 
"character" "character" "character" "character" "character"
```

In this contrived example, it doesn't matter.  Nevertheless, I don't understand why you would want the apply function to change the data types, and it is easy to think of cases where this would be an issue if not accounted for.

Any explanation as to why this is, how to prevent it (if it should be), or superior methodologies such as dplyr, etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `apply` works on matrices and arrays, which always have a single class. When you use apply on a mixed-class data set, it is coerced to a single class.

Comment: Alternative methods are linked from the help page `?apply`, like `lapply` and `aggregate`. Packages like dplyr, tidyr and data.table are very handy, but it depends what you need to do and whether you have time to learn them.

Comment: Note you want `class` instead of `typeof` if you want `factor` as a possible response and either `df[['Species']]` (`[[` instead of `[`) or `df[,'Species']`. Then you can do, e.g. `lapply(split(iris[1:5,],1:5),checkDataType)`. But using vectorization there is often a better choice than splitting by row.